# python embed in c++ memory leak

Tags: python, c++

When I embed python in c++，I got memory leak problem.

The following code is a simplified part, when running this, the memory increasing all over the running, which seems the `Py_DECREF` didn't work. Is there a way to collect the memory through the circulation so that the memory doesn't go up? Cause when I have a more complicated project the memory consuming is really huge.

```
#include <Python.h>

float test(double tedata[],int count){
    PyObject *datalist=PyList_New(count);   
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {    
      PyList_SetItem(datalist,i,Py_BuildValue("f",tedata[i]));
    }
    Py_DECREF(datalist);
    printf("for show more slowing");
    return 0;
}
void main(){ 
    float pr_label;   
    double tedata[]=   {44.0093,4.4871,305.012201,3.1311,11.1491,109.388698,34.0742,0.04,43.913701}; 
    int count = sizeof(tedata) / sizeof(double);

    Py_Initialize(); 
    for(int i=0;i<=500000;i++){
        test(tedata,count);     
    }
    Py_Finalize();  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not releasing the objects inside the datalist.
Each item in that is having a reference count as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You mean I should reasing the items in the datalist one by one?And how to do that?